# Bootstrap aligning h2 and accordion

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sidebar on the right that uses 3 elements of a bootstrap grid. I am trying to have the content always to the right of this sidebar (so they must always take up 9). I currently have an accordion and an h2, however I am having a difficult time left-aligning them with the rest of the content on the page. The sidebar is coded as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="list-group">
                <a href="example.html" class="list-group-item active">example</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Each "content div" is as follows (these are aligning properly)

```
    <div class="col-md-9 pull-right">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
             <div class="panel-heading">
                 <h4>title</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="panel-body">
                  <p>content</p>
             </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

This is the h2 and accordion that isn't properly aligning with the content.

```
<div class="col-md-9 pull-right">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
                 <h2 class="page-header col-md-9 pull-left">Action Strategies: What We Can Do Now</h2>
          </div>
       </div>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading together">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">What We Can Do Together</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul>
                    <li>list</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Image to help visualize the problem

[image]

without pull-right

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `pull-right` from the classes list:

```
<div class="col-md-9 pull-right">
<!-------------------^^^^^^^^^^ This is the culprit to pull it to the right.
```

The `pull-right` class just adds `float: right !important;` to the styles, which make the content to be pushed right.

Comment: The problem with that, is that when you remove pull-right, the content will go underneath the sidebar. I am trying to keep everything to the right of the sidebar.

Comment: @IsaacWatt Can you show a full demo, without `pull-right` and tell me what's the problem now? You can use [**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com) to demonstrate the code and the problem.

Comment: JSBin doesn't recognize that I am using bootstrap. I have added a photo to show what is happening without pull-right

Comment: @IsaacWatt That's okay, share me the JSBin link now... I guess you just need to include the Bootstrap styles.

Comment: did the link     
bootply.com/piBEMhZlAQ work for you?

Comment: @IsaacWatt Just saw it... It works. You want it in full width?

Comment: I want it to stack the same as the sections above it. it should not be underneath that sidebar column. It should line up to the right of it, as if the sidebar takes up 3 elements of the entire left screen.

Comment: it should be directly underneath and lined up with "resilience promotion"

Comment: @IsaacWatt Sure, add `col-md-offset-3` to this: `<div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">`. **Line number: 114**. Look at my fork here: **https://www.bootply.com/XlgX5gjZPF**

Comment: Ok perfect, thanks. One other quick thing in the following bootply: https://www.bootply.com/XlgX5gjZPF# how could I have the paragraph that starts with "One out of every five..." line up properly? your can see if you resize that it pulls right and doesn't have enough text to fill out the entire div, but I would like it to fit to the same size as the divs about it, and just have space on the right side of the paragraph if need be.

Comment: Sorry, try this link. https://www.bootply.com/UvFd2FiT2T it should be a completely different page.

Comment: @IsaacWatt I don't understand. There's no relation between the question and the last page you shared.

Comment: So on the page I shared, theres a box near the bottom (it is a paragraph that begins with "One out of every five"). I am trying top line it up with the paragraphs on top of it, however it doesn't work because of the pull-right. I tried replacing that (pull-right) with col-md-offset-3, but something really weird happens: It aligns properly, but the div box almost quadruples in height. Just wondering how this can be fixed? I have this problem in a few other locations of the website

Comment: @IsaacWatt It looks perfect to me.

Comment: If you resize it, do you not see how the div box that the paragraph is in pulls to the right, and leaves a little bit of space on the left?